# さくらドメインの設定反映までの表示画面についての質問

Tags: dns, network

さくらドメインの設定反映までの表示画面についての質問

現在、さくらドメインで取得した独自ドメインを使用し、さくらレンタルサーバーにマルチドメインで運用しています。しかし、一度、諸都合でマルチドメインを解除し、その後に再びマルチドメインの設定を行いました。すると、設定からおよそ2日ほど経過しているのですが、下のような画面から変更されません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

いまだにDNS側の設定が更新されていないのか、そもそもマルチドメインの設定が間違っているのか判断がつかずに困っています。

この状態でしばらく待機するべきでしょうか。
設定がおかしい場合は、どの設定を確認したら良いでしょうか。
質問の情報が足りない場合はご指摘ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちらの質問は直接「さくらドメイン」に対して問い合わせを行った方が具体的な回答が得られる気がします。

Comment: いえ、こちらで解決できました。回答ありがとうございました、どうやら.htaccessが原因だったようです。

Comment: 解決したようでしたらその内容を「自己回答」として記録を残してみてください。